# $(2^a-1)+b^2=2^c$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

$31+15^2=256$.

Are there infinitely many solutions to:

$(2^a-1)+b^2=2^c$ with a,b,c positive integer and a,b,c different each other.

Comment: I mean, you can just take $b = 1$ and $a=c$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this has infinitely many solutions. Let $t$ be any integer, and simply take $a = t+1$, $b = 2^t-1$ and $c = 2t$. Your example is precisely the case $t=4$.